# Sitecore 9.3 where do you specify search result appearance as grid?

Tags: sxa

New (and probably a dumb question). I have got a search result configured but it always displays as list. The docs say that you can display your results as grid but defaults to list but I can't find where to set that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the style of the search results using the variant for your results.

[image: Select a variant]

The rendering variant for the `Search Results` component specifies how each repeating section is rendered. OOTB the theme will render in a more grid-like fashion using the `horizontal` variant.

You could also create your own variant and use grid columns to render the results in a grid and then you can control exactly how many results per row you want to see.